# AdMob Ad showing black Ad but clickable

Tags: admob

I did the procedure of adding an ad to my app exactly it was supposed to.  A few days back everything was fine the test Banner ad and test Interstitial ad shows fine but from today IDK why it has become black but it is clickable. I opened my AdMob account and found nothing that may cause such a problem. Is it normal? My app is currently in the testing phase.

Here is a screenshot of the test banner ad from my app. (from a smartphone)
[image]

The problem of the same black is for Interstitial ads too.

Comment: I have the same issue for me. Have you solved this?

Comment: Idk accuratly. Some days ago the interstitial ad was working fine and day later banner ad was back again. But after that day same problem again.  I will launch the app soon on google play with real pub.  Id.  and will update if the problem persists.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your reply... my Problem Still Exists. But still, I'm Continuing my App Development with those black ad containers. if there any update I'll leave a comment here.

Comment: Is it working for you now?  It works fine for me, the test banner and interstitial ad are now good.

Comment: I checked after seeing your comment and now it's working fine.

Comment: have the same issue as of recently. nothing is helping

Comment: @warfo09 Keep developing, the ads are going black and coming back, I will update if this problem persists in  published app(my app is being reviewed currently).

Comment: Ads are working fine in published app,  I thinking there is some initial limit cap for showing ads which might cause problem or they might be ignoring some test ad requests. Here is link if you want: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guitarco.guitarcoscales

Comment: Can U show code? We cannot say anything without code :3

Comment: The implementation is same as https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner I cannot give code for now,  I think it's problem in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% this is a temporary ADMOB glitch on test blocks.
It appeared in my application itself and after a few days it went the same way. I haven't changed anything in the code.

[image]